# Instantiate VGG model for once only in Keras when predicting continuously?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, vgg-net

There are many online tutorial to guide how to predict one image for one time in Keras using pretrained model. For my case, I use VGG16 model in Keras, I need to predict images continuously, so I use for loop to load images, then pass it to predict function, it works well, but one prediction time is too long(~800ms in my machine, CPU only), here is code:

```
    
    # one full prediction function cost 800ms
    def predict(image):
        image = img_to_array(image)
        image = image / 255
        image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
        # build the VGG16 network, this line code cost 400~500ms
        model = keras.applications.VGG16(include_top=True, weights='imagenet')
        # Do predication
        prediction = model.predict(image)
        '''
        Process predication results
        '''

    '''
    some preprocess
    '''
    for img in imgs_list:
        predict(img)
```

The above code can work well, but it spend too much time for each prediction, whole function need 800ms, and build VGG network need 500ms, it cost too much. I want to remove this 500ms for each prediction for continuous predicting mode.

I try to put "model = keras.applications.VGG16(include_top=True, weights='imagenet')" this line code to the outside of predict function, define it globally or pass "model" as argument to function, but program will return error and end after first successful prediction.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zi/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1075, in _run
    subfeed, allow_tensor=True, allow_operation=False)
  File "/home/zi/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3590, in as_graph_element
    return self._as_graph_element_locked(obj, allow_tensor, allow_operation)
  File "/home/zi/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3669, in _as_graph_element_locked
    raise ValueError("Tensor %s is not an element of this graph." % obj)
ValueError: Tensor Tensor("input_1:0", shape=(?, ?, ?, 3), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "multi_classifier.py", line 256, in 
    predict(current_file_path)
  File "multi_classifier.py", line 184, in predict
    bottleneck_prediction = model_1.predict(image)
  File "/home/zi/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1835, in predict
    verbose=verbose, steps=steps)
  File "/home/zi/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1331, in _predict_loop
    batch_outs = f(ins_batch)
  File "/home/zi/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2482, in __call__
    **self.session_kwargs)
  File "/home/zi/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 900, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/zi/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1078, in _run
    'Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: ' + e.args[0])
TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Tensor Tensor("input_1:0", shape=(?, ?, ?, 3), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.
```

It seems like that I need to instantiate a VGG model for every prediction,  how do I change code to save the model build time?
Thanks.

Comment: It could be more helpful if you share your GitHub repo or whole code.  The code looks fine here. Maybe there is some error in Tensor Shape.